# nyroModal - Open a new nyromodal window onclick from a link which exists in a nyromodal and when closed take it back to already opened nyromodal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, nyromodal

I have a nyro modal window which opens up after checking some condition.
Now on click of a link from already opened nyromodal window, a new modal window opens.
But when I close it it closes both windows.

1. Please advise if we can still keep the first modal window open after closing second window.
2. How to remove the default close button option on the top right. We need to add a button and onclick close the modal window.

Many Thanks!!

This is the html

```
<a href="#show_popup" class="nyroModal" style="display:none;"></a>

Inside the modal window we have

<a id="tos" href="#tos_token" class="nyroModalChild">Terms & Conditions of Use</span></a>
```

and javascript

```
function showTermsNConditionsPopup()
{


//alert("setting cookie");
//$j('#show_popup').nyroModal();

$j('a.nyroModal').click();
$j('a.nyroModalChild').click();

//createCookie("bctermsnconditions","bctermsnconditions",1000);

}

$j(document).ready(function() {
    /* lightbox settings */
    $j.nyroModalSettings( {
        autoSizable: true,
        resizable: true,
        windowResize: true,
        width: 720,
        height: 680
        }
    );
});
```